# Unable to embed a screenshot to the SpecFlow html Report

Tags: screenshot, specflow

I am executing my automation scenarios using SpecFlow with Visual Studio.

I want to Embed a custom image to the HTML report which was generated by SpecFlow. That image is a screenshot i am taking whenever scenario is failed in Hooks.

Please help me out.

This is what i am seeing in the html report - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNqo7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the SeleniumWebTest sample project [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples). This sample project shows how to include a screenshot in your report. While the example is Selenium-based, the same principles apply to other frameworks.

A more in-depth explanation of how this works can be found [here](http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/Tutorial:-Customising-Reports/) under "Including Screenshots". Essentially, you need to abuse the console and use it to output your images' file paths.

Any data written to the console is available in your report (this is how the trace details are received by the report). You will need to parse the data written to the console and strip out the file path you want to embed. Make sure that you strip the image path completely so that you don't output the file path as part of the other trace information received from the console.

**Edit:** I've since discovered that there seems to be an issue with the template in the sample project. The following section in the template is bugged:
`class="log">@Raw(FormatTechMessages(traceEvent.TechMessages.TrimEnd()).Replace("SCREENSHOT[ <a href="http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/,-/" data-page=",-"<img width='1000' src=").Replace("</a> ]SCREENSHOT", "</img>"))</pre>`

This is because the console no longer seems to be formatting the file as a hyperlink, so the replacement string is never found. Updating this line in ReportTemplate.cshtml seems to have done the trick:
`<pre class="log">@Raw(FormatTechMessages(traceEvent.TechMessages.TrimEnd()).Replace("SCREENSHOT[ ", "<img width='1000' src=\"").Replace(" ]SCREENSHOT", "\"</img>"))</pre>`

As the console is no longer formatting the file as a hyperlink, you only need to replace the padding (in this case the "SCREENSHOT[]SCREENSHOT") from the string and instead enclose the path with the `<IMG>` tag. You also need to add the quotes around the file path.

Comment: Thank You for the response. I did exactly as mentioned in the SeleniumWebTest project. But still facing same problem.

--> AfterScenarioHook code - Console.WriteLine($"SCREENSHOT[ file:///{tempFileName} ]SCREENSHOT");

--> HTML report generated as - file:///C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Visual Studio 2015_Backup/Projects/MyProject.Specs/TestResults/tmp366D.jpg

Comment: Also i am using only SpecFlow, SpecRun. 
Is it available only in Paid Version?

Comment: Yes, the extended report features are only available in SpecFlow+ Runner, not in the open source version of SpecFlow.

Comment: If that screenshot is from the trace output, you need to add the corresponding HTML tags around the file path to get the image to show up. Otherwise it is just plain text.

Comment: Can you please give me an example on how to add corresponding HTML tags around the file path??

Comment: Check out the link I posted above. The code section in the sample project is the following:


    <pre class="log">@Raw(FormatTechMessages(traceEvent.TechMessages.TrimEnd()).Replace("SCREENSHOT[ <a href="http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/,-/" data-page=",-"<img width='1000' src=").Replace("</a> ]SCREENSHOT", "</img>"))</pre>

Comment: I have no idea that screenshot is from trace output or not. Can you please help me out how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like there is an error in the template in the sample project (which is weird, because it used to work). The console output is no longer formatting the file link (i.e. file:///...) as a hyperlink. This means there is no "<a href="specflow.org..." to replace and the replace code fails. The following change to the report template worked for me:
<pre class="log">@Raw(FormatTechMessages(traceEvent.TechMessages.TrimEnd()).Replace("SCREENSHOT[ ", "<img width='1000' src=\"").Replace(" ]SCREENSHOT", "\"</img>"))</pre>

Does that help? We will update the sample project ASAP.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But still same problem for me. If possible can u plz share the complete cshtml file that you are using. Also below is the line im using in cs file - Console.WriteLine($"SCREENSHOT[ file:///{tempFileName} ]SCREENSHOT");
__Package Details__: 
<package id="SpecFlow" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="SpecRun.Runner" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="SpecRun.SpecFlow" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net452" />

Comment: [My working template](http://specflow.org/temp/ReportTemplate.cshtml) ; I have made 2 changes to the template (IIRC): I reworked the replacement code as outlined above, and I added "RANDOM HIGHLIGHT THAT ITS THE RIGHT TEMPLATE" just before the screenshot so you can confirm that you are using my template in the final report's output. If that doesn't fix the issue, I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: It worked perfectly with your template :-). I think something is missing in the my template. Anyhow, it really helped me. Thank You for the solution. You are the best.

Comment: Yes, it worked well. Will post more questions if i found anything. Thank You. :)

Comment: Hi @Stephen McCafferty - Again im having issues with ReportTemplate.cshtml even thogugh i used your file. In one VS solution it is working and when i do the same thing in another VS solution it is thrown with compilation errors of ReportTemplate.cshtml file. Could you please help me how to resolve those errors as iam naive to .cshtml code. Thank You